# Vue typescript error when filtering and mapping a list

Tags: typescript, vue.js, openapi-generator, vetur

I wonder what I need to do in order to remove the folloing error from my code:

I have these interface:

```
export interface ClassifierTO {

   id?: number;
   classifierName?: string;
   userId?: number;
   intents?: Array<IntentTO>;
}
```

and:

```
export interface IntentTO {
   id?: number;
   intentName?: string;
   classifierId?: number;
   numberOfSamples?: number;
}
```

They were auto generate by `openapi-generator`.

When I used this inside a method of `class-component` of vue:

```
 let intents = this.classifier.intents
        .filter(intent => intent.intentName === "test")
        .map(intent => intent.numberOfSamples);
```

Then the result inside the console of vs code is:

```
Object is possibly 'undefined'
```

What do I need to change that this will no longer be seen as an error?
The typescript Version is `3.8.3`
and this is `tsconfig.json`

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "esnext",
    "module": "esnext",
    "strict": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "types": [
      "webpack-env"
    ],
    "paths": {
      "@/*": [
        "src/*"
      ]
    },
    "lib": [
      "esnext",
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "scripthost"
    ]
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.ts",
    "src/**/*.tsx",
    "src/**/*.vue",
    "tests/**/*.ts",
    "tests/**/*.tsx"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because in your `ClassifierTO` interface, all the properties/keys are optional. `intents?: Array<IntentTO>;` tells TypeScript that the `this.classifier.intents` may return undefined.

You can use the null coalescing operator to ensure that an array is returned all the time:

```
let intents = (classifier.intents ?? [])
    .filter(intent => intent.intentName === "test")
    .map(intent => intent.numberOfSamples);
```

Alternatively, simply update your interface such that `intents` is not an optional key.

Answer (score 1):

The question mark in your definition tells typescript that this is optional and could be empty.

```
export interface ClassifierTO {

   id?: number;
   classifierName?: string;
   userId?: number;
   intents?: Array<IntentTO>;
}
```

You could either remove the questionmark or just check wether intents is set.